# Cython compilation errors: '-mno-fused-madd'

Tags: xcode, python-2.7, clang, pip, cython

Whenever I compile Cython code (using `pyximport`) and frequently when I install packages from source (with `pip`) I get

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

What is this warning and what can I do to prevent it? I suspect I may not be able to prevent when `pip` triggers it, but is thre at least some way to configure `pyximport` to avoid it?

---

OS X 10.9, Python 2.7.5, Xcode clang 500.2.79

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-mno-fused-madd` is a gcc cpu target option. It is for enabling/disabling the generation of the fused multiply/add instructions (FMACs. Common in DSPs).

Since this is gcc-specific, clang gives a warning that it doesn't understand the option.

If you really don't want to see this warning you could try setting the default compiler by

```
env CC=/usr/bin/gcc pip install ...
```

This should also work for pyximport too (But I haven't tried).

Comment: So, basically an innocuous warning that I can just learn to not let bother me. If I've built my whole python stack with `clang` rather than `gcc`, would "switching" like this create any problems?

Comment: Shouldn't be any problems with switching, clang and gcc are ABI compatible so no problem there (unless you manually specify to use the new stdlib libc++ in which case the compatibility is only partial)

Answer (score 7):

The answer before didn't work for me, but it worked this to tell clang to ignore these error messages:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Solution found in [clang error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' (python package installation failure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa)

Comment: Thanks!  This almost worked for me.  If you are installing with `sudo` command you need to use the `-E` flag.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313407/clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd-python-package-installation-fa