# Error installing Pillow (and PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

If i use the command `sudo pip install Pillow`, it runs fine until the cleaning up stage: (this is the full error message from the log file)

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir /private/tmp/pip_build_root...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VaD2jT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
% (command_desc, proc.returncode,`enter code here` cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-VaD2jT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
```

I have the xcode command line tools installed. Really stuck on this one.

----UPDATE----
Ran `brew doctor` and cleared all errors. Installed all Pillow prerequisites successfully.

Here is the fill pip.log file: http://pastebin.com/08XD9JjM

Comment: Is there gcc installed?

Comment: @der_fenix yes in the /usr/bin directory

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem. It seems to be a problem caused by clang with Xcode 5.1. Look at the answer of this question:

[OS X Pillow installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727537/1179760)

My problem is solved by using the command in that answer:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install Pillow
```

It throws a lot of warnings. But everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It looks like this is a known issue for Mac OS X, either relating to XCode 5.1 or Mavericks 10.9: https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/527

This appears to be the most non-invasive way to resolve the issue:

> I was having this same problem and found that setting "CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments" and "CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments" resolved my issue (I didn't want to have to do a clean install to resolve it). This fix is described here: [Ansible Installation -clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390655/ansible-installation-clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd)

---

Original answer:

It looks like you're attempting to install Pillow on Mac OS X. Have you installed all the prerequisites, per [Pillow's Mac OS X installation instructions](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#mac-os-x-installation)?

pip should have written more output about the compilation error, if not to the console, then to its log file. You should have a look at the log file and post the relevant compilation error messages in your question, as well, to help with determining the issue.

Comment: Ive pasted the full pip.log file to pastebin

Comment: @Waddas I have updated my answer to point you to the GitHub Issue tracking this problem, plus one of several workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

`brew install python`

After running `brew doctor` it showed that due to the new installation there were unlinked kegs. To correct this i had to run `brew link --overwrite python`.

i could then run `sudo pip install Pillow` without any problems.