# Error installing Pillow

Tags: python, django, terminal, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to install Pillow for Python and i run this command on the terminal

```
sudo pip install Pillow
```

and i get this error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/_imagingtk.o'

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'build/temp.macosx-10.10-intel-2.7/Tk/tkImaging.o'

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Any solutions for this? i tried looking in stack overflow only similar errors but not the same one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing Pillow (and PIL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564623/error-installing-pillow-and-pil)

Comment: Did you try the solutions offered?

Comment: it's not duplicate of that question, it's different error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be the same as [this bug](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/790) in Pillow 2.5.0.

It's been fixed, to be released soon in 2.5.1.

To test the dev version:

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow.git
```

Or install version 2.4.0:

```
sudo pip install pillow==2.4.0
```

Edit: Pillow 2.5.1 has now been released so you can just do:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

Comment: @akashrajkn What about with the latest Pillow 3.4.2? Does it work with Pillow 2.4.0? Does it work with the latest dev version? What Python version are you using?

Comment: I tried  installing Pillow 3.4.2, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**First:** Install python-dev

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

**After:** install PILLOW

```
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
    
$ sudo apt-get build-dep pillow
    
$ sudo pip2 install pillow
Successfully installed pillow-6.2.2
```

This solution was tested on:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial.
```

It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pillow
```

(You may find additional possible answers at this similar question: [Installing Pillow/PIL on Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334776/installing-pillow-pil-on-mavericks/23094087#23094087))

Answer (score 0):

If you're on macOS, try: `brew install libtiff libjpeg webp littlecms`