# Fail to install lxml using pip

Tags: python, lxml

This is the command I used to install lxml:

```
sudo pip install lxml
```

And I got the following message in the Cleaning Up stage:

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,     tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rUFjFN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/georgejor/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

After that, I got:

```
ImportError: No module named lxml
```

Please help. Thanks!

The following output is from pip.log:

```
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /private/tmp/pip_build_root...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rUFjFN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 706, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-rUFjFN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml
```

Comment: This means that `lxml` was not properly installed. Do this `cat /Users/georgejor/Library/Logs/pip.log` and show that to us in the question.

Comment: Ok i've just added. Hope it can help.

Comment: It looks like you don't have setuptools installed. Install setuptools using `pip install setuptools`

Comment: When I run pip install setuptools, it shows: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Cleaning up...

Comment: and I use pip to install lxml, same message

Comment: When you ran `pip install lxml`, did you get any error messages?

Comment: No, but the red color message after Cleaning Up...

Comment: Okay, what system are you on?

Comment: OSX 10.10 with python 2.7 and pip 1.5.6

Comment: The log segment given isn't helpful. We need to know why the compile failed, not anything about the attempted cleanup _after_ the compile. If I were to place money on the issue, I'd put mine on @ragingSloth's answer (which I'm only not upvoting because I have serious issues with using SO as a forum for installation-support questions rather than programming questions).

Comment: I had a similar problem but installing llvmlite, after many hours of debugging my friend found out that it was using the wrong version of LLVM.

Answer (score 12):

Just install these stuff :

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev  python-dev  python-setuptools
```

Then try again :

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: this worked for me. Although blindly copying various programs to install I have no idea about is known not to be a good idea but it did work :-)

Answer (score 1):

lxml has C depenedencies, often I run into issues when I'm missing `libxslt` or `libxml2`. Are you sure that all non python dependencies are installed?

Comment: I'm on Linux, trying to install llvmlite and this didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question.

[Error installing Pillow (and PIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564623/error-installing-pillow-and-pil)

Are you using a MacOS? Maybe you can try to update the commandline tools and try 'brew' tool.
If not, you can try to install pip and easy_intall tools again, and update it.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html