# Issue deploying Python app to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

```
Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-SDg1nL/av/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8eCgWx-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-SDg1nL/av/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I'm a python noobie, not sure what's going on here.

Please let me know what additional info would help, thanks.

Comment: Include requirements.txt in your question ---> `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The `av` package was throwing an error:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27178619/3973137 helped me