# cython install failed (-mno-fused-madd unknown argument)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython

```
reating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Cython
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Cython/Plex
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I got this error while installing Cython from setup.py.
I was installing the scikit-learn package while get the same error. (-mno-fused-madd unknown argument)

Is there anything, any package needed before I install cython?

Many thanks

Comment: You don't actually need Cython to install scikit-learn, only to modify it.

Comment: It is related to the new xcode command line tools. It broke quite a lot in the python mac world. See here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22427311/870769

Answer (score 0):

You need probably need to install another C compiler. Try compiling it with GCC.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

Alternatively, you can edit the configure script and change the compiler flags.

On a side note, this seems like it is a bug you should report.

Comment: would you please indicate which flag I should change to?

Comment: Just remove the flag. Clang is telling you it does not know this flag. Although clang is gaining ground, GCC is de-facto the standard for many FOSS project. Hence, I would also try compiling it with GCC.