# MySQLdb Clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'

Tags: python, clang, mysql-python, llvm5.1

I am having a problem here and I already have spent a few days looking for a solution but so far nothing.

I need to set up my python environment and I am having problems with MySQLbd when I try to install it I get this error message:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
```

Currently I am using Mac OX 10.8.5

my python version is:

```
>>> print (sys.version) 
2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)]
```

Please if anyone can help me I will be really thankful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390655/ansible-installation-clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I was using XCode 5.1 and command line version 5 
that's the problem, python isn't compatible with GCC 5.1 I just downloaded the old GCC version on apple site and install it, now everything is ok!