# Installing Pillow, getting -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, python-imaging-library

I cannot get pillow installed.

```
(env)noah:cupalensic2 broinjc$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
(env)noah:cupalensic2 broinjc$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

I ran `pip install mezzanine` and when it got to satisfying pillow it screwed up...

```
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -arch x86_64 -DHAVE_LIBZ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/opt/X11/include/freetype2 -I/Users/broinjc/cupalensic2/env/build/pillow/libImaging -I/Users/broinjc/cupalensic2/env/include -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/X11/include -I/usr/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/_imaging.o

clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Users/broinjc/cupalensic2/env/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/broinjc/cupalensic2/env/build/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/lg/y_cwnrnd3rn4x_j1sbd1mg_h0000gn/T/pip-o0HQHe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/broinjc/cupalensic2/env/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/broinjc/cupalensic2/env/build/pillow
Storing complete log in /Users/broinjc/.pip/pip.log
```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue with OSX and recent Xcode upgrade.

Instructions how to avoid the issue are here:

[Ansible Installation -clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390655/ansible-installation-clang-error-unknown-argument-mno-fused-madd)

This should do the trick::

```
  ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install Pillow
```

Comment: it should possibly noted that this workaround will not work in the future