# Error when installing from requirements.txt of web project with pip

Tags: python, django, dependencies, pip, python-imaging-library

This is the error message I received

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-xGZuOG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/Pillow
```

The full terminal output from sudo pip install -r requirements.txt is http://pastebin.com/CAvW67f2

The content of requirements:

```
Django==1.6.1
EasyProcess==0.1.6
Pillow==2.3.0
South==0.8.4
Whoosh==2.6.0
bottle==0.11.6
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django-bootstrap3==2.6.1
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==18.0
httplib2==0.8
pyscreenshot==0.3.2
pystache==0.5.3
python-instagram==0.8.0
simplejson==3.3.2
static==1.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
yolk==0.4.3
```

I'm completely lost - thanks for any help on this

Comment: show us the content of `requirements.txt`

Comment: Sure - I've added the contents above

Comment: is your pip brew installed?

Comment: As far as I know I didn't install pip through brew. I do have brew installed though

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in your bash before installing:

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697440/cc-failed-with-exit-status-1-error-when-install-python-library)

Comment: Line 665: `error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL': Permission denied`
Perhaps you need to run with sudo?

Comment: "pip install --user -r requirements.txt" worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in your bash before installing your requirements:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144307/installing-pillow-getting-wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future)