# Error / Failure installing watchdog python on MacOS X

Tags: python, homebrew, easy-install, watchdog, python-watchdog

I want to create a python program that continously monitors a directory for any change and if a change hapens like creation or modification it should execure a shell script via exec.
For that reason I am trying to use watchdog on my MacOsX Mavriks. But every time I try to install it I get an error saying
I do it via

> sudo easy_install watchdog

```
Searching for watchdog

Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/watchdog/
Best match: watchdog 0.7.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/w/watchdog/watchdog-0.7.1.tar.gz#md5=ffec8b4afd1058e76f6c664ade8a0de7
Processing watchdog-0.7.1.tar.gz
Running watchdog-0.7.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Z2T0_T/watchdog-0.7.1/egg-dist-tmp-rxk3TS
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/source/_themes/.git*'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have also installed all its dependencies including homebrew.

Is there any other FAM I can run easily on my mac or How will this thing work

Comment: Have you tried installing it using `pip`?

Comment: I dont have it in my system
but I have tried to install it with its source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra archflag.

> sudo ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future" easy_install watchdog

This is an OSX update issue. See this similar (but not duplicate) question [Installing Pillow, getting -Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144307/installing-pillow-getting-wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future)